# Halogen to LED conversion on multi-light fixture not working

Tags: led

I have a fixture with 4 MR16 (two pin) halogen bulbs. If I replace 2 of the halogen bulbs with LED's all bulbs work. If I replace 3 halogen bulbs with LED's all the bulbs act like a strobe light (not flickering because it is a constant on/off pattern). If I replace all halogen bulbs with LED's none of the bulbs work.

The fixture does not have a dimmer.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  Something important hasn't been mentioned.   Is there a 12 volt DC power supply?  Motion sensor?  Lighted switch? Smart switch maybe an older one?  12V DC power supply maybe?

Comment: Generally MR16’s are 12v....

Comment: is it possible they are wired in series? if not, replace the driver/transformer/controller or whatever it's called locally

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely a mix of old and new technology: the power supply for the old halogen incandescent lamps is a newer electronic converter, rather than a transformer. Some of these converters have a minimum current for operation, which the LED's don't meet.

You have a few options:

- Replace the existing power supply with [one designed for LED lighting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007ME2HMQ) (This is a generic example; choose one that meets your needs).
- Run with two of each type. You'll save some energy over all-incandescent, but not as much. In addition, the difference in color temperature may be an advantage -- a more complete spectrum, or a disadvantage -- noticeable mismatch in color.
- Try a different brand of MR16 LED lamp... but there's no guarantee it would work better unless the lamp is specified to work with the particular model supply in your fixture.